# Let $f$ be a function such that $g(y)=\sup_{x\in \Bbb{R}} [xy-f(x)]$ is finite. Show that $f$ satisfies $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function having the property that for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ the value of the expression $$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} [xy-f(x)]$$ is finite. Define $g(y)=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} [xy-f(x)]$ for $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Then show that $f$ must satisfy  $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}=+\infty$.

The solution given is:

> We are to show that, $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=\infty$. In other words, this is equivalent to showing that, $\forall M>0$ $\exists K\gt 0$ such that, $\frac{f(x)}{|x|}\gt M,\forall |x|\gt K.$
>
> Let us the assume that the above statement is false. We aim for a contradiction.
>
> This means, we assume that $\exists M>0,\forall N>0,\exists x\in\Bbb R,$ such that, $\frac {f(x)}{|x|}\leq M$ for $|x|\gt N.$
>
> So, for $N=1,\exists x=x_1\in\Bbb R$ such that, $\frac{f(x_1)}{|x_1|}\leq M,$ where, $x_1>N=1.$
>
> For $N=2,\exists x=x_2\in\Bbb R$ such that, $\frac{f(x_2)}{|x_2|}\leq M,$ where, $x_2>N=2.$
>
> Continuing like this, we obtain a sequence $(x_n)\in \Bbb R$ such that, $\lim x_n=\infty$ and $\frac{f(x_n)}{|x_n|}\leq M,\forall n\in\Bbb N.$
>
> This means, $-f(x_n)\geq -M|x_n|,\forall n\in\Bbb N.$
>
> If infinitely many of our $x_n$ are positive, we have a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ consisting of only the positive terms of  $(x_n).$
>
> So, for $y>M$ we have, $g(y)=\sup _{x\in\Bbb R} [xy-f(x)]\geq xy-f(x),\forall x\in\Bbb R.$
>
> This means, $g(y)\geq x_{n_k}y-f(x_{n_k})\geq x_{n_k}y-M|x_{n_{k}}|=x_{n_k}y-Mx_{n_k}=x_{n_k}(y-M).$
>
> This means as $k\to\infty$ $x_{n_k}\to\infty$ and hence, $g(y)\to\infty$, a contradiction.
>
> So, we may conclude, that, there must only be finitely many $x_n>0$ and therefore, we assume, that there are infinitely many negative terms in $x_n.$
>
> If infinitely many of our $x_n$ are negative, we have a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ consisting of only the negative terms of  $(x_n).$
>
> Now, $-f(x_n)\geq -M|x_n|,\forall n\in\Bbb N$ implies $-f(x_{n_k})\geq -M|x_{n_k}|=Mx_{n_k},\forall k\in\Bbb N.$
>
> Thus for all $y\in\Bbb R$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ we have, $g(y)\geq x_{n_k}y-f(x_{n_k})\geq yx_{n_k}+Mx_{n_k}=(y+M)x_{n_k}.$
>
> We get a contradiction if $y<-M.$ This compketes the proof.

Now, I have two questions:

- In the first, part, where they wrote,

> This means as $k\to\infty$ $x_{n_k}\to\infty$ and hence, $g(y)\to\infty$, a contradiction

the part, $x_{n_k}\to\infty$ and hence, $g(y)\to\infty$ makes a complete sense, but I don't get why is this supposed to be a contradiction?

- They also wrote a statement,

> We get a contradiction if $y<-M$

in the proof. I don't again get where is the contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(y)$ tending to infinity when $k$ tends to infinity with $y$ constant in regards to $k$ does not make sense, hence the first contradiction. The second contradiction uses the same issue.